# Ethereum, Geth, Clef, ipc... Establish interaction between Geth and Clef

Tags: go-ethereum, ipc

I want to set up interaction between Geth and Clef in accordance with the instructions on the official website Ethereum -

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started

In Clef I use the command -

clef --keystore geth-tutorial/keystore --configdir geth-tutorial/clef --chainid 11155111

In another attempt I also added an explicit path to the command line for creating the ipc-file -

--ipcpath ...

But the result still does not meet expectations.
After that, the terminal returns me, in particular, the path to ipc-file

IPC endpoint opened                      url=\.\pipe\clef.ipc

I look at this path, but this file is not there.
I run Geth. And as expected Geth returns a message in the terminal that there is no ipc-file:

Fatal: Failed to set account manager backends: error connecting to external signer: Invalid pipe address 'geth-tutorial/clef/clef.ipc'.

The question is... Why the ipc files are not created? What am I doing wrong?